# How to take out the first part of array?

Tags: php, arrays

The following function out-puts an array and html.

I don't want to have

```
<li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci_okadadesign/index.php/admin/menus/r">r</a></li>
```

Could anyone tell me  how to achive it please?

Function

```
function getTopMenus(){
     $data[0] = 'root';
     $this->db->where('parentid',0);
     $Q = $this->db->get('menus');
     if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
       foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
         $data[] = $row;
       }
    }
    $Q->free_result();  
    return $data; 
 }
```

print_r():

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 24
            [name] => Main menu
            [shortdesc] => mainmenu
            [status] => active
            [parentid] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 25
            [name] => Galleri 1
            [shortdesc] => galleri1
            [status] => active
            [parentid] => 0
        )
)
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci_okadadesign/index.php/admin/menus">menus</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci_okadadesign/index.php/admin/menus/r">r</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci_okadadesign/index.php/admin/menus/mainmenu">Main menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci_okadadesign/index.php/admin/menus/galleri1">Galleri 1</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a bunch of menu items defined in your database. If there's a menu item in there titled 'r' all you have to do is delete that row and that `<li>` will go away.

Answer (score 0):

[array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)() is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CodeIgniter? You can refine the query saved in `$Q` using `get_where` instead of `get` (see [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)).